# Unable to import github repo in bitbucket using import repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, github-actions

I am importing a repo that is in GitHub to bitbucket using the import statement. Looks like an SSH key issue to me. Also, the repo which I am trying to import is a private repo within my organization. Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that if the redacted information is actually sensitive, you might want to use a black thick bar instead of these thin lines. At least some parts are still readable..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the remote GitHub clone has failed, using an HTTPS URL, then no SSH keys are involved.

Double-check the password used. It is possible it requires *not* the GitHub user account password, but a *token* ([PAT: Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)) associated to that account, for the clone to succeed.

See "[GitHub: Creating a personal access token (classic)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic)"

Comment: In the documentation, it says that we have to enter the password for the user who has access to that repo and not PAT.

Comment: @AkshaySeth Still, I would try a token. The documentation might be outdated.

Comment: @AkshaySeth: Also, note that a PAT *is* a password, of sorts - it's just a special *kind* of password (and the only kind that Git accepts here).

Comment: Thanks!
Did the trick for me!
Here is the link to GitHub docs, with instructions on how to create the PAT via GitHub UI:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic

Just in case...

Comment: @provisota Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to include your link.